# Random Record MongoDB Usage

Tags: php, mongodb, radio-button

I have the following PHP snippet which displays MongoDB records randomly.

```
foreach ($cursor as $obj)
//foreach ($result as $obj)
{
   $result = $c->find()->limit( 20 )->skip(mt_rand( 0, $c->count() ))->getNext();
echo ' '.$result["question"].'<br><br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                <input type="radio"> '.$result["ch1"].'<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                <input type="radio"> '.$result["ch2"].'<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                              <input type="radio"> '.$result["ch3"].'</p>';

}
```

I have 2 issues in this.

1) I wanted 20 records to be displayed but it is echoing all the records from DB.

2)This displays a set of questions and multiple answers in a radio button which are stored in DB. My DB has correct answer for all these questions, now how to get these random questions printed above to check against the correct answer stored in DB with the option selected by user in the radio button?

Comment: I somehow resolved the 1) issue by adding the count. But here what must be done if I want to wait for 60 seconds to display one record and flush/refresh previous question to display 2nd question and wait for 60 seconds for the user to select answers and then flush previous questions to display 3rd question ...so on till the count reaches zero?